# wait must contain condition clause with until keyword

Tags: vhdl

The following VHDL is to be used to test bench a booth multiplier. I keep getting an error on the first wait statement during analysis and elaboration : "wait statement must contain condition clause with until keyword"
I have several working test benches written this way (i.e. signal assignment, wait for x ns, other assignment, wait for x ns ...). I can't seem to find what the error might be.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY BoothMultiplier_32_test IS
END BoothMultiplier_32_test;

ARCHITECTURE test_arch OF BoothMultiplier_32 IS

SIGNAL A_test           :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
SIGNAL B_test           :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
SIGNAL result_test  :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);

COMPONENT BoothMultiplier_32
    PORT (
        dataA, dataB    :   IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
        result          :   OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;

BEGIN
    DUT1: BoothMultiplier_32 
    PORT MAP(
        dataA=>A_test,
        dataB=>B_test,
        result=>result_test
    );

    testing : PROCESS
    BEGIN
        wait for 10 ns;
        A_test<=x"0000000A";
        B_test<=x"0000000A";
        --wait for 10 ns;
        --A_test<=x"10000000";
        --B_test<=x"00000010";
        --wait for 10 ns;
        --A_test<=x"FFFFFFFF";
        --B_test<=x"FFFFFFFF";
        wait;
    END PROCESS testing;

END ARCHITECTURE test_arch;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only observable error in your code is:

```
ARCHITECTURE test_arch OF BoothMultiplier_32 IS
```

Should be:

```
ARCHITECTURE test_arch OF BoothMultiplier_32_test IS
```

Preceding your entity and architecture pair with a dummy BoothMultiplier_32 and using the above correction:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity boothmultiplier_32 is
    port (
        dataa, datab    :   in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        result          :   out std_logic_vector (63 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of boothmultiplier_32 is
begin
end architecture;

LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY BoothMultiplier_32_test IS
END BoothMultiplier_32_test;

ARCHITECTURE test_arch OF BoothMultiplier_32_test IS

SIGNAL A_test           :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
SIGNAL B_test           :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
SIGNAL result_test  :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0);

COMPONENT BoothMultiplier_32
    PORT (
        dataA, dataB    :   IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
        result          :   OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 downto 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;

BEGIN
    DUT1: BoothMultiplier_32 
    PORT MAP(
        dataA=>A_test,
        dataB=>B_test,
        result=>result_test
    );

    testing : PROCESS
    BEGIN
        wait for 10 ns;
        A_test<=x"0000000A";
        B_test<=x"0000000A";
        --wait for 10 ns;
        --A_test<=x"10000000";
        --B_test<=x"00000010";
        --wait for 10 ns;
        --A_test<=x"FFFFFFFF";
        --B_test<=x"FFFFFFFF";
        wait;
    END PROCESS testing;

END ARCHITECTURE test_arch;
```

And the code then analyzes, elaborates and runs using the  elaboration and run target boothMultiplier_32_test (while doing nothing interesting but none the less showing proper connectivity).

Perhaps you could tell us what tool you're having trouble with?